# How to set a newtwork with two objectives?

Tags: machine-learning, keras

Suppose I have a `x_train`, `y1_train` and `y2_train`.

I want to construct a network (such as simple MLP) to fit `y1_train` and to be low correlated with `y2_train` (or to fit `-y2_train`) simultaneously.

How could I achieve this goal? Is the custom loss function a good solution?

I use keras as my tool.

Answer (score 1):

So this problem is less of a Deep learning problem and more of a logical problem. Your y1_train and y2_train can be modelled along with a pointer label that points what output to be considered in the output. Lets say we create the concatenated output as follows:

```py
[[0/1],[y1_train], [y2_train]]
```

Where `0` could represent weather the label to be selected is `y1` or `y2` and so on.

But if you are planning to create a little more complex output and train different outputs on different loss functions, here is an article you should refer to [Multiple output tutorial/examples](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/multiple-output-tutorial-examples/3050/4) and [Custom Loss Function for Unequal Weighted Multiple-Output Node Regression](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/custom-loss-function-for-unequal-weighted-multiple-output-node-regression/20910)